# How to increment a database field in Spring MVC based on a time period

Tags: java, database, spring

I have two fields in a database table - `date` and `student number`. I want to increment the `student number` every time I insert something into this table.

I would like to take period-based cut-offs for the `student number` field. The first record to be inserted in a period should get inserted with `student number = 1`, the second with `student number = 2`, the third with `student number = 3` and so on.

For example, each day could be treated as one period. Then, if today is `05/02/2016 (May 2, 2016)` the first student record to get inserted would get `student number = 1`. When the date changes to `05/03/2016 (May 3, 2016)` I want the `student number` to be reset to 1.

So the database table should look like this:

```
 ---------------------------
| date     | student number |
 ---------------------------
| 05/02/16 | 1              |
| 05/02/16 | 2              |
| 05/02/16 | 3              |
| 05/03/16 | 1              |
 ---------------------------
```

This is in my controller code for insertion:

```
student.setStudentNo(job.getStudentType()
                     .concat("_")
                     .concat(Constants.datetimeJobDF.format(new Date()))
                     .concat("_"));
```

Comment: 1. Create a supporting database table (say `student_number_sequence`) with two fields - `date` and `current_value`.  2. When you want to insert a record into the main table, run a query on the supporting table, locking the row for the current date - `SELECT current_value FROM student_number_sequence WHERE date = ?`.  3. If no record is found, insert one for the current date and treat `current_value` as `1`, otherwise update the record with `current_value = current_value + 1`.  4. Insert record into the main table.  5. Commit transaction to release the lock on the supporting table.

Comment: can you give me some sample codes or references in which I can look on? I am kinda confuse since I am still not used with spring thanks